# Filter out values in dictionary of lists with tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filter

I have a dictionary:

```
{(0, 0): [(1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)], (0, 1): [(1, 1), (-1, 1), (0, 0), (0, 2)], (0, 2): [(1, 2), (-1, 2), (0, 1), (0, 3)], (0, 3): [(1, 3), (-1, 3), (0, 2), (0, 4)], (0, 4): [(1, 4), (-1, 4), (0, 3), (0, 5)], (0, 5): [(1, 5), (-1, 5), (0, 4), (0, 6)], (0, 6): [(1, 6), (-1, 6), (0, 5), (0, 7)], (0, 7): [(1, 7), (-1, 7), (0, 6), (0, 8)], (0, 8): [(1, 8), (-1, 8), (0, 7), (0, 9)], (0, 9): [(1, 9), (-1, 9), (0, 8), (0, 10)], (0, 10): [(1, 10), (-1, 10), (0, 9), (0, 11)], (0, 11): [(1, 11), (-1, 11), (0, 10), (0, 12)], (0, 12): [(1, 12), (-1, 12), (0, 11), (0, 13)], (0, 13): [(1, 13), (-1, 13), (0, 12), (0, 14)], (0, 14): [(1, 14), (-1, 14), (0, 13), (0, 15)], (0, 15): [(1, 15), (-1, 15), (0, 14), (0, 16)], (0, 16): [(1, 16), (-1, 16), (0, 15), (0, 17)], (0, 17): [(1, 17), (-1, 17), (0, 16), (0, 18)], (0, 18): [(1, 18), (-1, 18), (0, 17), (0, 19)], (0, 19): [(1, 19), (-1, 19), (0, 18), (0, 20)], (1, 0): [(2, 0), (0, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1)], (1, 1): [(2, 1), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2)], (1, 2): [(2, 2), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 3)], (1, 3): [(2, 3), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 4)], (1, 4): [(2, 4), (0, 4), (1, 3), (1, 5)], (1, 5): [(2, 5), (0, 5), (1, 4), (1, 6)], (1, 6): [(2, 6), (0, 6), (1, 5), (1, 7)], (1, 7): [(2, 7), (0, 7), (1, 6), (1, 8)], (1, 8): [(2, 8), (0, 8), (1, 7), (1, 9)], (1, 9): [(2, 9), (0, 9), (1, 8), (1, 10)], (1, 10): [(2, 10), (0, 10), (1, 9), (1, 11)], (1, 11): [(2, 11), (0, 11), (1, 10), (1, 12)], (1, 12): [(2, 12), (0, 12), (1, 11), (1, 13)], (1, 13): [(2, 13), (0, 13), (1, 12), (1, 14)], (1, 14): [(2, 14), (0, 14), (1, 13), (1, 15)], (1, 15): [(2, 15), (0, 15), (1, 14), (1, 16)], (1, 16): [(2, 16), (0, 16), (1, 15), (1, 17)], (1, 17): [(2, 17), (0, 17), (1, 16), (1, 18)], (1, 18): [(2, 18), (0, 18), (1, 17), (1, 19)], (1, 19): [(2, 19), (0, 19), (1, 18), (1, 20)], (2, 0): [(3, 0), (1, 0), (2, -1), (2, 1)], (2, 1): [(3, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 2)], (2, 2): [(3, 2), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3)], (2, 3): [(3, 3), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 4)], (2, 4): [(3, 4), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 5)], (2, 5): [(3, 5), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 6)], (2, 6): [(3, 6), (1, 6), (2, 5), (2, 7)], (2, 7): [(3, 7), (1, 7), (2, 6), (2, 8)], (2, 8): [(3, 8), (1, 8), (2, 7), (2, 9)], (2, 9): [(3, 9), (1, 9), (2, 8), (2, 10)], (2, 10): [(3, 10), (1, 10), (2, 9), (2, 11)], (2, 11): [(3, 11), (1, 11), (2, 10), (2, 12)], (2, 12): [(3, 12), (1, 12), (2, 11), (2, 13)], (2, 13): [(3, 13), (1, 13), (2, 12), (2, 14)], (2, 14): [(3, 14), (1, 14), (2, 13), (2, 15)], (2, 15): [(3, 15), (1, 15), (2, 14), (2, 16)], (2, 16): [(3, 16), (1, 16), (2, 15), (2, 17)], (2, 17): [(3, 17), (1, 17), (2, 16), (2, 18)], (2, 18): [(3, 18), (1, 18), (2, 17), (2, 19)], (2, 19): [(3, 19), (1, 19), (2, 18), (2, 20)], (3, 0): [(4, 0), (2, 0), (3, -1), (3, 1)], (3, 1): [(4, 1), (2, 1), (3, 0), (3, 2)], (3, 2): [(4, 2), (2, 2), (3, 1), (3, 3)], (3, 3): [(4, 3), (2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 4)], (3, 4): [(4, 4), (2, 4), (3, 3), (3, 5)], (3, 5): [(4, 5), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 6)], (3, 6): [(4, 6), (2, 6), (3, 5), (3, 7)], (3, 7): [(4, 7), (2, 7), (3, 6), (3, 8)], (3, 8): [(4, 8), (2, 8), (3, 7), (3, 9)], (3, 9): [(4, 9), (2, 9), (3, 8), (3, 10)], (3, 10): [(4, 10), (2, 10), (3, 9), (3, 11)], (3, 11): [(4, 11), (2, 11), (3, 10), (3, 12)], (3, 12): [(4, 12), (2, 12), (3, 11), (3, 13)], (3, 13): [(4, 13), (2, 13), (3, 12), (3, 14)], (3, 14): [(4, 14), (2, 14), (3, 13), (3, 15)], (3, 15): [(4, 15), (2, 15), (3, 14), (3, 16)], (3, 16): [(4, 16), (2, 16), (3, 15), (3, 17)], (3, 17): [(4, 17), (2, 17), (3, 16), (3, 18)], (3, 18): [(4, 18), (2, 18), (3, 17), (3, 19)], (3, 19): [(4, 19), (2, 19), (3, 18), (3, 20)], (4, 0): [(5, 0), (3, 0), (4, -1), (4, 1)], (4, 1): [(5, 1), (3, 1), (4, 0), (4, 2)], (4, 2): [(5, 2), (3, 2), (4, 1), (4, 3)], (4, 3): [(5, 3), (3, 3), (4, 2), (4, 4)], (4, 4): [(5, 4), (3, 4), (4, 3), (4, 5)], (4, 5): [(5, 5), (3, 5), (4, 4), (4, 6)], (4, 6): [(5, 6), (3, 6), (4, 5), (4, 7)], (4, 7): [(5, 7), (3, 7), (4, 6), (4, 8)], (4, 8): [(5, 8), (3, 8), (4, 7), (4, 9)], (4, 9): [(5, 9), (3, 9), (4, 8), (4, 10)], (4, 10): [(5, 10), (3, 10), (4, 9), (4, 11)], (4, 11): [(5, 11), (3, 11), (4, 10), (4, 12)], (4, 12): [(5, 12), (3, 12), (4, 11), (4, 13)], (4, 13): [(5, 13), (3, 13), (4, 12), (4, 14)], (4, 14): [(5, 14), (3, 14), (4, 13), (4, 15)], (4, 15): [(5, 15), (3, 15), (4, 14), (4, 16)], (4, 16): [(5, 16), (3, 16), (4, 15), (4, 17)], (4, 17): [(5, 17), (3, 17), (4, 16), (4, 18)], (4, 18): [(5, 18), (3, 18), (4, 17), (4, 19)], (4, 19): [(5, 19), (3, 19), (4, 18), (4, 20)], (5, 0): [(6, 0), (4, 0), (5, -1), (5, 1)], (5, 1): [(6, 1), (4, 1), (5, 0), (5, 2)], (5, 2): [(6, 2), (4, 2), (5, 1), (5, 3)], (5, 3): [(6, 3), (4, 3), (5, 2), (5, 4)], (5, 4): [(6, 4), (4, 4), (5, 3), (5, 5)], (5, 5): [(6, 5), (4, 5), (5, 4), (5, 6)], (5, 6): [(6, 6), (4, 6), (5, 5), (5, 7)], (5, 7): [(6, 7), (4, 7), (5, 6), (5, 8)], (5, 8): [(6, 8), (4, 8), (5, 7), (5, 9)], (5, 9): [(6, 9), (4, 9), (5, 8), (5, 10)], (5, 10): [(6, 10), (4, 10), (5, 9), (5, 11)], (5, 11): [(6, 11), (4, 11), (5, 10), (5, 12)], (5, 12): [(6, 12), (4, 12), (5, 11), (5, 13)], (5, 13): [(6, 13), (4, 13), (5, 12), (5, 14)], (5, 14): [(6, 14), (4, 14), (5, 13), (5, 15)], (5, 15): [(6, 15), (4, 15), (5, 14), (5, 16)], (5, 16): [(6, 16), (4, 16), (5, 15), (5, 17)], (5, 17): [(6, 17), (4, 17), (5, 16), (5, 18)], (5, 18): [(6, 18), (4, 18), (5, 17), (5, 19)], (5, 19): [(6, 19), (4, 19), (5, 18), (5, 20)], (6, 0): [(7, 0), (5, 0), (6, -1), (6, 1)], (6, 1): [(7, 1), (5, 1), (6, 0), (6, 2)], (6, 2): [(7, 2), (5, 2), (6, 1), (6, 3)], (6, 3): [(7, 3), (5, 3), (6, 2), (6, 4)], (6, 4): [(7, 4), (5, 4), (6, 3), (6, 5)], (6, 5): [(7, 5), (5, 5), (6, 4), (6, 6)], (6, 6): [(7, 6), (5, 6), (6, 5), (6, 7)], (6, 7): [(7, 7), (5, 7), (6, 6), (6, 8)], (6, 8): [(7, 8), (5, 8), (6, 7), (6, 9)], (6, 9): [(7, 9), (5, 9), (6, 8), (6, 10)], (6, 10): [(7, 10), (5, 10), (6, 9), (6, 11)], (6, 11): [(7, 11), (5, 11), (6, 10), (6, 12)], (6, 12): [(7, 12), (5, 12), (6, 11), (6, 13)], (6, 13): [(7, 13), (5, 13), (6, 12), (6, 14)], (6, 14): [(7, 14), (5, 14), (6, 13), (6, 15)], (6, 15): [(7, 15), (5, 15), (6, 14), (6, 16)], (6, 16): [(7, 16), (5, 16), (6, 15), (6, 17)], (6, 17): [(7, 17), (5, 17), (6, 16), (6, 18)], (6, 18): [(7, 18), (5, 18), (6, 17), (6, 19)], (6, 19): [(7, 19), (5, 19), (6, 18), (6, 20)], (7, 0): [(8, 0), (6, 0), (7, -1), (7, 1)], (7, 1): [(8, 1), (6, 1), (7, 0), (7, 2)], (7, 2): [(8, 2), (6, 2), (7, 1), (7, 3)], (7, 3): [(8, 3), (6, 3), (7, 2), (7, 4)], (7, 4): [(8, 4), (6, 4), (7, 3), (7, 5)], (7, 5): [(8, 5), (6, 5), (7, 4), (7, 6)], (7, 6): [(8, 6), (6, 6), (7, 5), (7, 7)], (7, 7): [(8, 7), (6, 7), (7, 6), (7, 8)], (7, 8): [(8, 8), (6, 8), (7, 7), (7, 9)], (7, 9): [(8, 9), (6, 9), (7, 8), (7, 10)], (7, 10): [(8, 10), (6, 10), (7, 9), (7, 11)], (7, 11): [(8, 11), (6, 11), (7, 10), (7, 12)], (7, 12): [(8, 12), (6, 12), (7, 11), (7, 13)], (7, 13): [(8, 13), (6, 13), (7, 12), (7, 14)], (7, 14): [(8, 14), (6, 14), (7, 13), (7, 15)], (7, 15): [(8, 15), (6, 15), (7, 14), (7, 16)], (7, 16): [(8, 16), (6, 16), (7, 15), (7, 17)], (7, 17): [(8, 17), (6, 17), (7, 16), (7, 18)], (7, 18): [(8, 18), (6, 18), (7, 17), (7, 19)], (7, 19): [(8, 19), (6, 19), (7, 18), (7, 20)], (8, 0): [(9, 0), (7, 0), (8, -1), (8, 1)], (8, 1): [(9, 1), (7, 1), (8, 0), (8, 2)], (8, 2): [(9, 2), (7, 2), (8, 1), (8, 3)], (8, 3): [(9, 3), (7, 3), (8, 2), (8, 4)], (8, 4): [(9, 4), (7, 4), (8, 3), (8, 5)], (8, 5): [(9, 5), (7, 5), (8, 4), (8, 6)], (8, 6): [(9, 6), (7, 6), (8, 5), (8, 7)], (8, 7): [(9, 7), (7, 7), (8, 6), (8, 8)], (8, 8): [(9, 8), (7, 8), (8, 7), (8, 9)], (8, 9): [(9, 9), (7, 9), (8, 8), (8, 10)], (8, 10): [(9, 10), (7, 10), (8, 9), (8, 11)], (8, 11): [(9, 11), (7, 11), (8, 10), (8, 12)], (8, 12): [(9, 12), (7, 12), (8, 11), (8, 13)], (8, 13): [(9, 13), (7, 13), (8, 12), (8, 14)], (8, 14): [(9, 14), (7, 14), (8, 13), (8, 15)], (8, 15): [(9, 15), (7, 15), (8, 14), (8, 16)], (8, 16): [(9, 16), (7, 16), (8, 15), (8, 17)], (8, 17): [(9, 17), (7, 17), (8, 16), (8, 18)], (8, 18): [(9, 18), (7, 18), (8, 17), (8, 19)], (8, 19): [(9, 19), (7, 19), (8, 18), (8, 20)], (9, 0): [(10, 0), (8, 0), (9, -1), (9, 1)], (9, 1): [(10, 1), (8, 1), (9, 0), (9, 2)], (9, 2): [(10, 2), (8, 2), (9, 1), (9, 3)], (9, 3): [(10, 3), (8, 3), (9, 2), (9, 4)], (9, 4): [(10, 4), (8, 4), (9, 3), (9, 5)], (9, 5): [(10, 5), (8, 5), (9, 4), (9, 6)], (9, 6): [(10, 6), (8, 6), (9, 5), (9, 7)], (9, 7): [(10, 7), (8, 7), (9, 6), (9, 8)], (9, 8): [(10, 8), (8, 8), (9, 7), (9, 9)], (9, 9): [(10, 9), (8, 9), (9, 8), (9, 10)], (9, 10): [(10, 10), (8, 10), (9, 9), (9, 11)], (9, 11): [(10, 11), (8, 11), (9, 10), (9, 12)], (9, 12): [(10, 12), (8, 12), (9, 11), (9, 13)], (9, 13): [(10, 13), (8, 13), (9, 12), (9, 14)], (9, 14): [(10, 14), (8, 14), (9, 13), (9, 15)], (9, 15): [(10, 15), (8, 15), (9, 14), (9, 16)], (9, 16): [(10, 16), (8, 16), (9, 15), (9, 17)], (9, 17): [(10, 17), (8, 17), (9, 16), (9, 18)], (9, 18): [(10, 18), (8, 18), (9, 17), (9, 19)], (9, 19): [(10, 19), (8, 19), (9, 18), (9, 20)], (10, 0): [(11, 0), (9, 0), (10, -1), (10, 1)], (10, 1): [(11, 1), (9, 1), (10, 0), (10, 2)], (10, 2): [(11, 2), (9, 2), (10, 1), (10, 3)], (10, 3): [(11, 3), (9, 3), (10, 2), (10, 4)], (10, 4): [(11, 4), (9, 4), (10, 3), (10, 5)], (10, 5): [(11, 5), (9, 5), (10, 4), (10, 6)], (10, 6): [(11, 6), (9, 6), (10, 5), (10, 7)], (10, 7): [(11, 7), (9, 7), (10, 6), (10, 8)], (10, 8): [(11, 8), (9, 8), (10, 7), (10, 9)], (10, 9): [(11, 9), (9, 9), (10, 8), (10, 10)], (10, 10): [(11, 10), (9, 10), (10, 9), (10, 11)], (10, 11): [(11, 11), (9, 11), (10, 10), (10, 12)], (10, 12): [(11, 12), (9, 12), (10, 11), (10, 13)], (10, 13): [(11, 13), (9, 13), (10, 12), (10, 14)], (10, 14): [(11, 14), (9, 14), (10, 13), (10, 15)], (10, 15): [(11, 15), (9, 15), (10, 14), (10, 16)], (10, 16): [(11, 16), (9, 16), (10, 15), (10, 17)], (10, 17): [(11, 17), (9, 17), (10, 16), (10, 18)], (10, 18): [(11, 18), (9, 18), (10, 17), (10, 19)], (10, 19): [(11, 19), (9, 19), (10, 18), (10, 20)], (11, 0): [(12, 0), (10, 0), (11, -1), (11, 1)], (11, 1): [(12, 1), (10, 1), (11, 0), (11, 2)], (11, 2): [(12, 2), (10, 2), (11, 1), (11, 3)], (11, 3): [(12, 3), (10, 3), (11, 2), (11, 4)], (11, 4): [(12, 4), (10, 4), (11, 3), (11, 5)], (11, 5): [(12, 5), (10, 5), (11, 4), (11, 6)], (11, 6): [(12, 6), (10, 6), (11, 5), (11, 7)], (11, 7): [(12, 7), (10, 7), (11, 6), (11, 8)], (11, 8): [(12, 8), (10, 8), (11, 7), (11, 9)], (11, 9): [(12, 9), (10, 9), (11, 8), (11, 10)], (11, 10): [(12, 10), (10, 10), (11, 9), (11, 11)], (11, 11): [(12, 11), (10, 11), (11, 10), (11, 12)], (11, 12): [(12, 12), (10, 12), (11, 11), (11, 13)], (11, 13): [(12, 13), (10, 13), (11, 12), (11, 14)], (11, 14): [(12, 14), (10, 14), (11, 13), (11, 15)], (11, 15): [(12, 15), (10, 15), (11, 14), (11, 16)], (11, 16): [(12, 16), (10, 16), (11, 15), (11, 17)], (11, 17): [(12, 17), (10, 17), (11, 16), (11, 18)], (11, 18): [(12, 18), (10, 18), (11, 17), (11, 19)], (11, 19): [(12, 19), (10, 19), (11, 18), (11, 20)], (12, 0): [(13, 0), (11, 0), (12, -1), (12, 1)], (12, 1): [(13, 1), (11, 1), (12, 0), (12, 2)], (12, 2): [(13, 2), (11, 2), (12, 1), (12, 3)], (12, 3): [(13, 3), (11, 3), (12, 2), (12, 4)], (12, 4): [(13, 4), (11, 4), (12, 3), (12, 5)], (12, 5): [(13, 5), (11, 5), (12, 4), (12, 6)], (12, 6): [(13, 6), (11, 6), (12, 5), (12, 7)], (12, 7): [(13, 7), (11, 7), (12, 6), (12, 8)], (12, 8): [(13, 8), (11, 8), (12, 7), (12, 9)], (12, 9): [(13, 9), (11, 9), (12, 8), (12, 10)], (12, 10): [(13, 10), (11, 10), (12, 9), (12, 11)], (12, 11): [(13, 11), (11, 11), (12, 10), (12, 12)], (12, 12): [(13, 12), (11, 12), (12, 11), (12, 13)], (12, 13): [(13, 13), (11, 13), (12, 12), (12, 14)], (12, 14): [(13, 14), (11, 14), (12, 13), (12, 15)], (12, 15): [(13, 15), (11, 15), (12, 14), (12, 16)], (12, 16): [(13, 16), (11, 16), (12, 15), (12, 17)], (12, 17): [(13, 17), (11, 17), (12, 16), (12, 18)], (12, 18): [(13, 18), (11, 18), (12, 17), (12, 19)], (12, 19): [(13, 19), (11, 19), (12, 18), (12, 20)], (13, 0): [(14, 0), (12, 0), (13, -1), (13, 1)], (13, 1): [(14, 1), (12, 1), (13, 0), (13, 2)], (13, 2): [(14, 2), (12, 2), (13, 1), (13, 3)], (13, 3): [(14, 3), (12, 3), (13, 2), (13, 4)], (13, 4): [(14, 4), (12, 4), (13, 3), (13, 5)], (13, 5): [(14, 5), (12, 5), (13, 4), (13, 6)], (13, 6): [(14, 6), (12, 6), (13, 5), (13, 7)], (13, 7): [(14, 7), (12, 7), (13, 6), (13, 8)], (13, 8): [(14, 8), (12, 8), (13, 7), (13, 9)], (13, 9): [(14, 9), (12, 9), (13, 8), (13, 10)], (13, 10): [(14, 10), (12, 10), (13, 9), (13, 11)], (13, 11): [(14, 11), (12, 11), (13, 10), (13, 12)], (13, 12): [(14, 12), (12, 12), (13, 11), (13, 13)], (13, 13): [(14, 13), (12, 13), (13, 12), (13, 14)], (13, 14): [(14, 14), (12, 14), (13, 13), (13, 15)], (13, 15): [(14, 15), (12, 15), (13, 14), (13, 16)], (13, 16): [(14, 16), (12, 16), (13, 15), (13, 17)], (13, 17): [(14, 17), (12, 17), (13, 16), (13, 18)], (13, 18): [(14, 18), (12, 18), (13, 17), (13, 19)], (13, 19): [(14, 19), (12, 19), (13, 18), (13, 20)], (14, 0): [(15, 0), (13, 0), (14, -1), (14, 1)], (14, 1): [(15, 1), (13, 1), (14, 0), (14, 2)], (14, 2): [(15, 2), (13, 2), (14, 1), (14, 3)], (14, 3): [(15, 3), (13, 3), (14, 2), (14, 4)], (14, 4): [(15, 4), (13, 4), (14, 3), (14, 5)], (14, 5): [(15, 5), (13, 5), (14, 4), (14, 6)], (14, 6): [(15, 6), (13, 6), (14, 5), (14, 7)], (14, 7): [(15, 7), (13, 7), (14, 6), (14, 8)], (14, 8): [(15, 8), (13, 8), (14, 7), (14, 9)], (14, 9): [(15, 9), (13, 9), (14, 8), (14, 10)], (14, 10): [(15, 10), (13, 10), (14, 9), (14, 11)], (14, 11): [(15, 11), (13, 11), (14, 10), (14, 12)], (14, 12): [(15, 12), (13, 12), (14, 11), (14, 13)], (14, 13): [(15, 13), (13, 13), (14, 12), (14, 14)], (14, 14): [(15, 14), (13, 14), (14, 13), (14, 15)], (14, 15): [(15, 15), (13, 15), (14, 14), (14, 16)], (14, 16): [(15, 16), (13, 16), (14, 15), (14, 17)], (14, 17): [(15, 17), (13, 17), (14, 16), (14, 18)], (14, 18): [(15, 18), (13, 18), (14, 17), (14, 19)], (14, 19): [(15, 19), (13, 19), (14, 18), (14, 20)], (15, 0): [(16, 0), (14, 0), (15, -1), (15, 1)], (15, 1): [(16, 1), (14, 1), (15, 0), (15, 2)], (15, 2): [(16, 2), (14, 2), (15, 1), (15, 3)], (15, 3): [(16, 3), (14, 3), (15, 2), (15, 4)], (15, 4): [(16, 4), (14, 4), (15, 3), (15, 5)], (15, 5): [(16, 5), (14, 5), (15, 4), (15, 6)], (15, 6): [(16, 6), (14, 6), (15, 5), (15, 7)], (15, 7): [(16, 7), (14, 7), (15, 6), (15, 8)], (15, 8): [(16, 8), (14, 8), (15, 7), (15, 9)], (15, 9): [(16, 9), (14, 9), (15, 8), (15, 10)], (15, 10): [(16, 10), (14, 10), (15, 9), (15, 11)], (15, 11): [(16, 11), (14, 11), (15, 10), (15, 12)], (15, 12): [(16, 12), (14, 12), (15, 11), (15, 13)], (15, 13): [(16, 13), (14, 13), (15, 12), (15, 14)], (15, 14): [(16, 14), (14, 14), (15, 13), (15, 15)], (15, 15): [(16, 15), (14, 15), (15, 14), (15, 16)], (15, 16): [(16, 16), (14, 16), (15, 15), (15, 17)], (15, 17): [(16, 17), (14, 17), (15, 16), (15, 18)], (15, 18): [(16, 18), (14, 18), (15, 17), (15, 19)], (15, 19): [(16, 19), (14, 19), (15, 18), (15, 20)], (16, 0): [(17, 0), (15, 0), (16, -1), (16, 1)], (16, 1): [(17, 1), (15, 1), (16, 0), (16, 2)], (16, 2): [(17, 2), (15, 2), (16, 1), (16, 3)], (16, 3): [(17, 3), (15, 3), (16, 2), (16, 4)], (16, 4): [(17, 4), (15, 4), (16, 3), (16, 5)], (16, 5): [(17, 5), (15, 5), (16, 4), (16, 6)], (16, 6): [(17, 6), (15, 6), (16, 5), (16, 7)], (16, 7): [(17, 7), (15, 7), (16, 6), (16, 8)], (16, 8): [(17, 8), (15, 8), (16, 7), (16, 9)], (16, 9): [(17, 9), (15, 9), (16, 8), (16, 10)], (16, 10): [(17, 10), (15, 10), (16, 9), (16, 11)], (16, 11): [(17, 11), (15, 11), (16, 10), (16, 12)], (16, 12): [(17, 12), (15, 12), (16, 11), (16, 13)], (16, 13): [(17, 13), (15, 13), (16, 12), (16, 14)], (16, 14): [(17, 14), (15, 14), (16, 13), (16, 15)], (16, 15): [(17, 15), (15, 15), (16, 14), (16, 16)], (16, 16): [(17, 16), (15, 16), (16, 15), (16, 17)], (16, 17): [(17, 17), (15, 17), (16, 16), (16, 18)], (16, 18): [(17, 18), (15, 18), (16, 17), (16, 19)], (16, 19): [(17, 19), (15, 19), (16, 18), (16, 20)], (17, 0): [(18, 0), (16, 0), (17, -1), (17, 1)], (17, 1): [(18, 1), (16, 1), (17, 0), (17, 2)], (17, 2): [(18, 2), (16, 2), (17, 1), (17, 3)], (17, 3): [(18, 3), (16, 3), (17, 2), (17, 4)], (17, 4): [(18, 4), (16, 4), (17, 3), (17, 5)], (17, 5): [(18, 5), (16, 5), (17, 4), (17, 6)], (17, 6): [(18, 6), (16, 6), (17, 5), (17, 7)], (17, 7): [(18, 7), (16, 7), (17, 6), (17, 8)], (17, 8): [(18, 8), (16, 8), (17, 7), (17, 9)], (17, 9): [(18, 9), (16, 9), (17, 8), (17, 10)], (17, 10): [(18, 10), (16, 10), (17, 9), (17, 11)], (17, 11): [(18, 11), (16, 11), (17, 10), (17, 12)], (17, 12): [(18, 12), (16, 12), (17, 11), (17, 13)], (17, 13): [(18, 13), (16, 13), (17, 12), (17, 14)], (17, 14): [(18, 14), (16, 14), (17, 13), (17, 15)], (17, 15): [(18, 15), (16, 15), (17, 14), (17, 16)], (17, 16): [(18, 16), (16, 16), (17, 15), (17, 17)], (17, 17): [(18, 17), (16, 17), (17, 16), (17, 18)], (17, 18): [(18, 18), (16, 18), (17, 17), (17, 19)], (17, 19): [(18, 19), (16, 19), (17, 18), (17, 20)], (18, 0): [(19, 0), (17, 0), (18, -1), (18, 1)], (18, 1): [(19, 1), (17, 1), (18, 0), (18, 2)], (18, 2): [(19, 2), (17, 2), (18, 1), (18, 3)], (18, 3): [(19, 3), (17, 3), (18, 2), (18, 4)], (18, 4): [(19, 4), (17, 4), (18, 3), (18, 5)], (18, 5): [(19, 5), (17, 5), (18, 4), (18, 6)], (18, 6): [(19, 6), (17, 6), (18, 5), (18, 7)], (18, 7): [(19, 7), (17, 7), (18, 6), (18, 8)], (18, 8): [(19, 8), (17, 8), (18, 7), (18, 9)], (18, 9): [(19, 9), (17, 9), (18, 8), (18, 10)], (18, 10): [(19, 10), (17, 10), (18, 9), (18, 11)], (18, 11): [(19, 11), (17, 11), (18, 10), (18, 12)], (18, 12): [(19, 12), (17, 12), (18, 11), (18, 13)], (18, 13): [(19, 13), (17, 13), (18, 12), (18, 14)], (18, 14): [(19, 14), (17, 14), (18, 13), (18, 15)], (18, 15): [(19, 15), (17, 15), (18, 14), (18, 16)], (18, 16): [(19, 16), (17, 16), (18, 15), (18, 17)], (18, 17): [(19, 17), (17, 17), (18, 16), (18, 18)], (18, 18): [(19, 18), (17, 18), (18, 17), (18, 19)], (18, 19): [(19, 19), (17, 19), (18, 18), (18, 20)], (19, 0): [(20, 0), (18, 0), (19, -1), (19, 1)], (19, 1): [(20, 1), (18, 1), (19, 0), (19, 2)], (19, 2): [(20, 2), (18, 2), (19, 1), (19, 3)], (19, 3): [(20, 3), (18, 3), (19, 2), (19, 4)], (19, 4): [(20, 4), (18, 4), (19, 3), (19, 5)], (19, 5): [(20, 5), (18, 5), (19, 4), (19, 6)], (19, 6): [(20, 6), (18, 6), (19, 5), (19, 7)], (19, 7): [(20, 7), (18, 7), (19, 6), (19, 8)], (19, 8): [(20, 8), (18, 8), (19, 7), (19, 9)], (19, 9): [(20, 9), (18, 9), (19, 8), (19, 10)], (19, 10): [(20, 10), (18, 10), (19, 9), (19, 11)], (19, 11): [(20, 11), (18, 11), (19, 10), (19, 12)], (19, 12): [(20, 12), (18, 12), (19, 11), (19, 13)], (19, 13): [(20, 13), (18, 13), (19, 12), (19, 14)], (19, 14): [(20, 14), (18, 14), (19, 13), (19, 15)], (19, 15): [(20, 15), (18, 15), (19, 14), (19, 16)], (19, 16): [(20, 16), (18, 16), (19, 15), (19, 17)], (19, 17): [(20, 17), (18, 17), (19, 16), (19, 18)], (19, 18): [(20, 18), (18, 18), (19, 17), (19, 19)], (19, 19): [(20, 19), (18, 19), (19, 18), (19, 20)]}
```

Sorry for cramming in so much elements

Anyways I want to filter out the tuples in the values of the keys in the dictionary I want to delete the tuple which contains a number smaller than 0 or larger than 20, if you want further explanation in details I will add it but I think I explained it pretty accurate to what I want.

Expected output for example:

```
{(0, 0): [(1, 0), (0, 1)], (0, 1): [(1, 1), (0, 0), (0, 2)], (19, 6): [(18, 6), (19, 5), (19, 7)], (19, 7): [(18, 7), (19, 6), (19, 8)]..}
```

The output right now:

```
{(0, 0): [(1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)], (0, 1): [(1, 1), (-1, 1), (0, 0), (0, 2)], (19, 6): [(20, 6), (18, 6), (19, 5), (19, 7)], (19, 7): [(20, 7), (18, 7), (19, 6), (19, 8)]..}
```

Hope it's understandable!

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO is not a coding service. Try, post what you tried, and let us know why it did not work.

Comment: Post your [mcve]

Comment: You post 'output right now', which suggests you have attempted to write some code already, which is not working. It would help if you could post your attempted solution

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through your dictionary and construct a new filtered list for each existing list:

```py
d = {(0, 0): [(1, 0), (-1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)], (0, 1): [(1, 1), (-1, 1), (0, 0), (0, 2)], (0, 2): [(1, 2), (-1, 2), (0, 1), (0, 3)], (0, 3): [(1, 3), (-1, 3), (0, 2), (0, 4)], (0, 4): [(1, 4), (-1, 4), (0, 3), (0, 5)], (0, 5): [(1, 5), (-1, 5), (0, 4), (0, 6)], (0, 6): [(1, 6), (-1, 6), (0, 5), (0, 7)], (0, 7): [(1, 7), (-1, 7), (0, 6), (0, 8)], (0, 8): [(1, 8), (-1, 8), (0, 7), (0, 9)], (0, 9): [(1, 9), (-1, 9), (0, 8), (0, 10)], (0, 10): [(1, 10), (-1, 10), (0, 9), (0, 11)], (0, 11): [(1, 11), (-1, 11), (0, 10), (0, 12)], (0, 12): [(1, 12), (-1, 12), (0, 11), (0, 13)], (0, 13): [(1, 13), (-1, 13), (0, 12), (0, 14)], (0, 14): [(1, 14), (-1, 14), (0, 13), (0, 15)], (0, 15): [(1, 15), (-1, 15), (0, 14), (0, 16)], (0, 16): [(1, 16), (-1, 16), (0, 15), (0, 17)], (0, 17): [(1, 17), (-1, 17), (0, 16), (0, 18)], (0, 18): [(1, 18), (-1, 18), (0, 17), (0, 19)], (0, 19): [(1, 19), (-1, 19), (0, 18), (0, 20)], (1, 0): [(2, 0), (0, 0), (1, -1), (1, 1)], (1, 1): [(2, 1), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 2)], (1, 2): [(2, 2), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 3)], (1, 3): [(2, 3), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 4)], (1, 4): [(2, 4), (0, 4), (1, 3), (1, 5)], (1, 5): [(2, 5), (0, 5), (1, 4), (1, 6)], (1, 6): [(2, 6), (0, 6), (1, 5), (1, 7)], (1, 7): [(2, 7), (0, 7), (1, 6), (1, 8)], (1, 8): [(2, 8), (0, 8), (1, 7), (1, 9)], (1, 9): [(2, 9), (0, 9), (1, 8), (1, 10)], (1, 10): [(2, 10), (0, 10), (1, 9), (1, 11)], (1, 11): [(2, 11), (0, 11), (1, 10), (1, 12)], (1, 12): [(2, 12), (0, 12), (1, 11), (1, 13)], (1, 13): [(2, 13), (0, 13), (1, 12), (1, 14)], (1, 14): [(2, 14), (0, 14), (1, 13), (1, 15)], (1, 15): [(2, 15), (0, 15), (1, 14), (1, 16)], (1, 16): [(2, 16), (0, 16), (1, 15), (1, 17)], (1, 17): [(2, 17), (0, 17), (1, 16), (1, 18)], (1, 18): [(2, 18), (0, 18), (1, 17), (1, 19)], (1, 19): [(2, 19), (0, 19), (1, 18), (1, 20)], (2, 0): [(3, 0), (1, 0), (2, -1), (2, 1)], (2, 1): [(3, 1), (1, 1), (2, 0), (2, 2)], (2, 2): [(3, 2), (1, 2), (2, 1), (2, 3)], (2, 3): [(3, 3), (1, 3), (2, 2), (2, 4)], (2, 4): [(3, 4), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 5)], (2, 5): [(3, 5), (1, 5), (2, 4), (2, 6)], (2, 6): [(3, 6), (1, 6), (2, 5), (2, 7)], (2, 7): [(3, 7), (1, 7), (2, 6), (2, 8)], (2, 8): [(3, 8), (1, 8), (2, 7), (2, 9)], (2, 9): [(3, 9), (1, 9), (2, 8), (2, 10)], (2, 10): [(3, 10), (1, 10), (2, 9), (2, 11)], (2, 11): [(3, 11), (1, 11), (2, 10), (2, 12)], (2, 12): [(3, 12), (1, 12), (2, 11), (2, 13)], (2, 13): [(3, 13), (1, 13), (2, 12), (2, 14)], (2, 14): [(3, 14), (1, 14), (2, 13), (2, 15)], (2, 15): [(3, 15), (1, 15), (2, 14), (2, 16)], (2, 16): [(3, 16), (1, 16), (2, 15), (2, 17)], (2, 17): [(3, 17), (1, 17), (2, 16), (2, 18)], (2, 18): [(3, 18), (1, 18), (2, 17), (2, 19)], (2, 19): [(3, 19), (1, 19), (2, 18), (2, 20)], (3, 0): [(4, 0), (2, 0), (3, -1), (3, 1)], (3, 1): [(4, 1), (2, 1), (3, 0), (3, 2)], (3, 2): [(4, 2), (2, 2), (3, 1), (3, 3)], (3, 3): [(4, 3), (2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 4)], (3, 4): [(4, 4), (2, 4), (3, 3), (3, 5)], (3, 5): [(4, 5), (2, 5), (3, 4), (3, 6)], (3, 6): [(4, 6), (2, 6), (3, 5), (3, 7)], (3, 7): [(4, 7), (2, 7), (3, 6), (3, 8)], (3, 8): [(4, 8), (2, 8), (3, 7), (3, 9)], (3, 9): [(4, 9), (2, 9), (3, 8), (3, 10)], (3, 10): [(4, 10), (2, 10), (3, 9), (3, 11)], (3, 11): [(4, 11), (2, 11), (3, 10), (3, 12)], (3, 12): [(4, 12), (2, 12), (3, 11), (3, 13)], (3, 13): [(4, 13), (2, 13), (3, 12), (3, 14)], (3, 14): [(4, 14), (2, 14), (3, 13), (3, 15)], (3, 15): [(4, 15), (2, 15), (3, 14), (3, 16)], (3, 16): [(4, 16), (2, 16), (3, 15), (3, 17)], (3, 17): [(4, 17), (2, 17), (3, 16), (3, 18)], (3, 18): [(4, 18), (2, 18), (3, 17), (3, 19)], (3, 19): [(4, 19), (2, 19), (3, 18), (3, 20)], (4, 0): [(5, 0), (3, 0), (4, -1), (4, 1)], (4, 1): [(5, 1), (3, 1), (4, 0), (4, 2)], (4, 2): [(5, 2), (3, 2), (4, 1), (4, 3)], (4, 3): [(5, 3), (3, 3), (4, 2), (4, 4)], (4, 4): [(5, 4), (3, 4), (4, 3), (4, 5)], (4, 5): [(5, 5), (3, 5), (4, 4), (4, 6)], (4, 6): [(5, 6), (3, 6), (4, 5), (4, 7)], (4, 7): [(5, 7), (3, 7), (4, 6), (4, 8)], (4, 8): [(5, 8), (3, 8), (4, 7), (4, 9)], (4, 9): [(5, 9), (3, 9), (4, 8), (4, 10)], (4, 10): [(5, 10), (3, 10), (4, 9), (4, 11)], (4, 11): [(5, 11), (3, 11), (4, 10), (4, 12)], (4, 12): [(5, 12), (3, 12), (4, 11), (4, 13)], (4, 13): [(5, 13), (3, 13), (4, 12), (4, 14)], (4, 14): [(5, 14), (3, 14), (4, 13), (4, 15)], (4, 15): [(5, 15), (3, 15), (4, 14), (4, 16)], (4, 16): [(5, 16), (3, 16), (4, 15), (4, 17)], (4, 17): [(5, 17), (3, 17), (4, 16), (4, 18)], (4, 18): [(5, 18), (3, 18), (4, 17), (4, 19)], (4, 19): [(5, 19), (3, 19), (4, 18), (4, 20)], (5, 0): [(6, 0), (4, 0), (5, -1), (5, 1)], (5, 1): [(6, 1), (4, 1), (5, 0), (5, 2)], (5, 2): [(6, 2), (4, 2), (5, 1), (5, 3)], (5, 3): [(6, 3), (4, 3), (5, 2), (5, 4)], (5, 4): [(6, 4), (4, 4), (5, 3), (5, 5)], (5, 5): [(6, 5), (4, 5), (5, 4), (5, 6)], (5, 6): [(6, 6), (4, 6), (5, 5), (5, 7)], (5, 7): [(6, 7), (4, 7), (5, 6), (5, 8)], (5, 8): [(6, 8), (4, 8), (5, 7), (5, 9)], (5, 9): [(6, 9), (4, 9), (5, 8), (5, 10)], (5, 10): [(6, 10), (4, 10), (5, 9), (5, 11)], (5, 11): [(6, 11), (4, 11), (5, 10), (5, 12)], (5, 12): [(6, 12), (4, 12), (5, 11), (5, 13)], (5, 13): [(6, 13), (4, 13), (5, 12), (5, 14)], (5, 14): [(6, 14), (4, 14), (5, 13), (5, 15)], (5, 15): [(6, 15), (4, 15), (5, 14), (5, 16)], (5, 16): [(6, 16), (4, 16), (5, 15), (5, 17)], (5, 17): [(6, 17), (4, 17), (5, 16), (5, 18)], (5, 18): [(6, 18), (4, 18), (5, 17), (5, 19)], (5, 19): [(6, 19), (4, 19), (5, 18), (5, 20)], (6, 0): [(7, 0), (5, 0), (6, -1), (6, 1)], (6, 1): [(7, 1), (5, 1), (6, 0), (6, 2)], (6, 2): [(7, 2), (5, 2), (6, 1), (6, 3)], (6, 3): [(7, 3), (5, 3), (6, 2), (6, 4)], (6, 4): [(7, 4), (5, 4), (6, 3), (6, 5)], (6, 5): [(7, 5), (5, 5), (6, 4), (6, 6)], (6, 6): [(7, 6), (5, 6), (6, 5), (6, 7)], (6, 7): [(7, 7), (5, 7), (6, 6), (6, 8)], (6, 8): [(7, 8), (5, 8), (6, 7), (6, 9)], (6, 9): [(7, 9), (5, 9), (6, 8), (6, 10)], (6, 10): [(7, 10), (5, 10), (6, 9), (6, 11)], (6, 11): [(7, 11), (5, 11), (6, 10), (6, 12)], (6, 12): [(7, 12), (5, 12), (6, 11), (6, 13)], (6, 13): [(7, 13), (5, 13), (6, 12), (6, 14)], (6, 14): [(7, 14), (5, 14), (6, 13), (6, 15)], (6, 15): [(7, 15), (5, 15), (6, 14), (6, 16)], (6, 16): [(7, 16), (5, 16), (6, 15), (6, 17)], (6, 17): [(7, 17), (5, 17), (6, 16), (6, 18)], (6, 18): [(7, 18), (5, 18), (6, 17), (6, 19)], (6, 19): [(7, 19), (5, 19), (6, 18), (6, 20)], (7, 0): [(8, 0), (6, 0), (7, -1), (7, 1)], (7, 1): [(8, 1), (6, 1), (7, 0), (7, 2)], (7, 2): [(8, 2), (6, 2), (7, 1), (7, 3)], (7, 3): [(8, 3), (6, 3), (7, 2), (7, 4)], (7, 4): [(8, 4), (6, 4), (7, 3), (7, 5)], (7, 5): [(8, 5), (6, 5), (7, 4), (7, 6)], (7, 6): [(8, 6), (6, 6), (7, 5), (7, 7)], (7, 7): [(8, 7), (6, 7), (7, 6), (7, 8)], (7, 8): [(8, 8), (6, 8), (7, 7), (7, 9)], (7, 9): [(8, 9), (6, 9), (7, 8), (7, 10)], (7, 10): [(8, 10), (6, 10), (7, 9), (7, 11)], (7, 11): [(8, 11), (6, 11), (7, 10), (7, 12)], (7, 12): [(8, 12), (6, 12), (7, 11), (7, 13)], (7, 13): [(8, 13), (6, 13), (7, 12), (7, 14)], (7, 14): [(8, 14), (6, 14), (7, 13), (7, 15)], (7, 15): [(8, 15), (6, 15), (7, 14), (7, 16)], (7, 16): [(8, 16), (6, 16), (7, 15), (7, 17)], (7, 17): [(8, 17), (6, 17), (7, 16), (7, 18)], (7, 18): [(8, 18), (6, 18), (7, 17), (7, 19)], (7, 19): [(8, 19), (6, 19), (7, 18), (7, 20)], (8, 0): [(9, 0), (7, 0), (8, -1), (8, 1)], (8, 1): [(9, 1), (7, 1), (8, 0), (8, 2)], (8, 2): [(9, 2), (7, 2), (8, 1), (8, 3)], (8, 3): [(9, 3), (7, 3), (8, 2), (8, 4)], (8, 4): [(9, 4), (7, 4), (8, 3), (8, 5)], (8, 5): [(9, 5), (7, 5), (8, 4), (8, 6)], (8, 6): [(9, 6), (7, 6), (8, 5), (8, 7)], (8, 7): [(9, 7), (7, 7), (8, 6), (8, 8)], (8, 8): [(9, 8), (7, 8), (8, 7), (8, 9)], (8, 9): [(9, 9), (7, 9), (8, 8), (8, 10)], (8, 10): [(9, 10), (7, 10), (8, 9), (8, 11)], (8, 11): [(9, 11), (7, 11), (8, 10), (8, 12)], (8, 12): [(9, 12), (7, 12), (8, 11), (8, 13)], (8, 13): [(9, 13), (7, 13), (8, 12), (8, 14)], (8, 14): [(9, 14), (7, 14), (8, 13), (8, 15)], (8, 15): [(9, 15), (7, 15), (8, 14), (8, 16)], (8, 16): [(9, 16), (7, 16), (8, 15), (8, 17)], (8, 17): [(9, 17), (7, 17), (8, 16), (8, 18)], (8, 18): [(9, 18), (7, 18), (8, 17), (8, 19)], (8, 19): [(9, 19), (7, 19), (8, 18), (8, 20)], (9, 0): [(10, 0), (8, 0), (9, -1), (9, 1)], (9, 1): [(10, 1), (8, 1), (9, 0), (9, 2)], (9, 2): [(10, 2), (8, 2), (9, 1), (9, 3)], (9, 3): [(10, 3), (8, 3), (9, 2), (9, 4)], (9, 4): [(10, 4), (8, 4), (9, 3), (9, 5)], (9, 5): [(10, 5), (8, 5), (9, 4), (9, 6)], (9, 6): [(10, 6), (8, 6), (9, 5), (9, 7)], (9, 7): [(10, 7), (8, 7), (9, 6), (9, 8)], (9, 8): [(10, 8), (8, 8), (9, 7), (9, 9)], (9, 9): [(10, 9), (8, 9), (9, 8), (9, 10)], (9, 10): [(10, 10), (8, 10), (9, 9), (9, 11)], (9, 11): [(10, 11), (8, 11), (9, 10), (9, 12)], (9, 12): [(10, 12), (8, 12), (9, 11), (9, 13)], (9, 13): [(10, 13), (8, 13), (9, 12), (9, 14)], (9, 14): [(10, 14), (8, 14), (9, 13), (9, 15)], (9, 15): [(10, 15), (8, 15), (9, 14), (9, 16)], (9, 16): [(10, 16), (8, 16), (9, 15), (9, 17)], (9, 17): [(10, 17), (8, 17), (9, 16), (9, 18)], (9, 18): [(10, 18), (8, 18), (9, 17), (9, 19)], (9, 19): [(10, 19), (8, 19), (9, 18), (9, 20)], (10, 0): [(11, 0), (9, 0), (10, -1), (10, 1)], (10, 1): [(11, 1), (9, 1), (10, 0), (10, 2)], (10, 2): [(11, 2), (9, 2), (10, 1), (10, 3)], (10, 3): [(11, 3), (9, 3), (10, 2), (10, 4)], (10, 4): [(11, 4), (9, 4), (10, 3), (10, 5)], (10, 5): [(11, 5), (9, 5), (10, 4), (10, 6)], (10, 6): [(11, 6), (9, 6), (10, 5), (10, 7)], (10, 7): [(11, 7), (9, 7), (10, 6), (10, 8)], (10, 8): [(11, 8), (9, 8), (10, 7), (10, 9)], (10, 9): [(11, 9), (9, 9), (10, 8), (10, 10)], (10, 10): [(11, 10), (9, 10), (10, 9), (10, 11)], (10, 11): [(11, 11), (9, 11), (10, 10), (10, 12)], (10, 12): [(11, 12), (9, 12), (10, 11), (10, 13)], (10, 13): [(11, 13), (9, 13), (10, 12), (10, 14)], (10, 14): [(11, 14), (9, 14), (10, 13), (10, 15)], (10, 15): [(11, 15), (9, 15), (10, 14), (10, 16)], (10, 16): [(11, 16), (9, 16), (10, 15), (10, 17)], (10, 17): [(11, 17), (9, 17), (10, 16), (10, 18)], (10, 18): [(11, 18), (9, 18), (10, 17), (10, 19)], (10, 19): [(11, 19), (9, 19), (10, 18), (10, 20)], (11, 0): [(12, 0), (10, 0), (11, -1), (11, 1)], (11, 1): [(12, 1), (10, 1), (11, 0), (11, 2)], (11, 2): [(12, 2), (10, 2), (11, 1), (11, 3)], (11, 3): [(12, 3), (10, 3), (11, 2), (11, 4)], (11, 4): [(12, 4), (10, 4), (11, 3), (11, 5)], (11, 5): [(12, 5), (10, 5), (11, 4), (11, 6)], (11, 6): [(12, 6), (10, 6), (11, 5), (11, 7)], (11, 7): [(12, 7), (10, 7), (11, 6), (11, 8)], (11, 8): [(12, 8), (10, 8), (11, 7), (11, 9)], (11, 9): [(12, 9), (10, 9), (11, 8), (11, 10)], (11, 10): [(12, 10), (10, 10), (11, 9), (11, 11)], (11, 11): [(12, 11), (10, 11), (11, 10), (11, 12)], (11, 12): [(12, 12), (10, 12), (11, 11), (11, 13)], (11, 13): [(12, 13), (10, 13), (11, 12), (11, 14)], (11, 14): [(12, 14), (10, 14), (11, 13), (11, 15)], (11, 15): [(12, 15), (10, 15), (11, 14), (11, 16)], (11, 16): [(12, 16), (10, 16), (11, 15), (11, 17)], (11, 17): [(12, 17), (10, 17), (11, 16), (11, 18)], (11, 18): [(12, 18), (10, 18), (11, 17), (11, 19)], (11, 19): [(12, 19), (10, 19), (11, 18), (11, 20)], (12, 0): [(13, 0), (11, 0), (12, -1), (12, 1)], (12, 1): [(13, 1), (11, 1), (12, 0), (12, 2)], (12, 2): [(13, 2), (11, 2), (12, 1), (12, 3)], (12, 3): [(13, 3), (11, 3), (12, 2), (12, 4)], (12, 4): [(13, 4), (11, 4), (12, 3), (12, 5)], (12, 5): [(13, 5), (11, 5), (12, 4), (12, 6)], (12, 6): [(13, 6), (11, 6), (12, 5), (12, 7)], (12, 7): [(13, 7), (11, 7), (12, 6), (12, 8)], (12, 8): [(13, 8), (11, 8), (12, 7), (12, 9)], (12, 9): [(13, 9), (11, 9), (12, 8), (12, 10)], (12, 10): [(13, 10), (11, 10), (12, 9), (12, 11)], (12, 11): [(13, 11), (11, 11), (12, 10), (12, 12)], (12, 12): [(13, 12), (11, 12), (12, 11), (12, 13)], (12, 13): [(13, 13), (11, 13), (12, 12), (12, 14)], (12, 14): [(13, 14), (11, 14), (12, 13), (12, 15)], (12, 15): [(13, 15), (11, 15), (12, 14), (12, 16)], (12, 16): [(13, 16), (11, 16), (12, 15), (12, 17)], (12, 17): [(13, 17), (11, 17), (12, 16), (12, 18)], (12, 18): [(13, 18), (11, 18), (12, 17), (12, 19)], (12, 19): [(13, 19), (11, 19), (12, 18), (12, 20)], (13, 0): [(14, 0), (12, 0), (13, -1), (13, 1)], (13, 1): [(14, 1), (12, 1), (13, 0), (13, 2)], (13, 2): [(14, 2), (12, 2), (13, 1), (13, 3)], (13, 3): [(14, 3), (12, 3), (13, 2), (13, 4)], (13, 4): [(14, 4), (12, 4), (13, 3), (13, 5)], (13, 5): [(14, 5), (12, 5), (13, 4), (13, 6)], (13, 6): [(14, 6), (12, 6), (13, 5), (13, 7)], (13, 7): [(14, 7), (12, 7), (13, 6), (13, 8)], (13, 8): [(14, 8), (12, 8), (13, 7), (13, 9)], (13, 9): [(14, 9), (12, 9), (13, 8), (13, 10)], (13, 10): [(14, 10), (12, 10), (13, 9), (13, 11)], (13, 11): [(14, 11), (12, 11), (13, 10), (13, 12)], (13, 12): [(14, 12), (12, 12), (13, 11), (13, 13)], (13, 13): [(14, 13), (12, 13), (13, 12), (13, 14)], (13, 14): [(14, 14), (12, 14), (13, 13), (13, 15)], (13, 15): [(14, 15), (12, 15), (13, 14), (13, 16)], (13, 16): [(14, 16), (12, 16), (13, 15), (13, 17)], (13, 17): [(14, 17), (12, 17), (13, 16), (13, 18)], (13, 18): [(14, 18), (12, 18), (13, 17), (13, 19)], (13, 19): [(14, 19), (12, 19), (13, 18), (13, 20)], (14, 0): [(15, 0), (13, 0), (14, -1), (14, 1)], (14, 1): [(15, 1), (13, 1), (14, 0), (14, 2)], (14, 2): [(15, 2), (13, 2), (14, 1), (14, 3)], (14, 3): [(15, 3), (13, 3), (14, 2), (14, 4)], (14, 4): [(15, 4), (13, 4), (14, 3), (14, 5)], (14, 5): [(15, 5), (13, 5), (14, 4), (14, 6)], (14, 6): [(15, 6), (13, 6), (14, 5), (14, 7)], (14, 7): [(15, 7), (13, 7), (14, 6), (14, 8)], (14, 8): [(15, 8), (13, 8), (14, 7), (14, 9)], (14, 9): [(15, 9), (13, 9), (14, 8), (14, 10)], (14, 10): [(15, 10), (13, 10), (14, 9), (14, 11)], (14, 11): [(15, 11), (13, 11), (14, 10), (14, 12)], (14, 12): [(15, 12), (13, 12), (14, 11), (14, 13)], (14, 13): [(15, 13), (13, 13), (14, 12), (14, 14)], (14, 14): [(15, 14), (13, 14), (14, 13), (14, 15)], (14, 15): [(15, 15), (13, 15), (14, 14), (14, 16)], (14, 16): [(15, 16), (13, 16), (14, 15), (14, 17)], (14, 17): [(15, 17), (13, 17), (14, 16), (14, 18)], (14, 18): [(15, 18), (13, 18), (14, 17), (14, 19)], (14, 19): [(15, 19), (13, 19), (14, 18), (14, 20)], (15, 0): [(16, 0), (14, 0), (15, -1), (15, 1)], (15, 1): [(16, 1), (14, 1), (15, 0), (15, 2)], (15, 2): [(16, 2), (14, 2), (15, 1), (15, 3)], (15, 3): [(16, 3), (14, 3), (15, 2), (15, 4)], (15, 4): [(16, 4), (14, 4), (15, 3), (15, 5)], (15, 5): [(16, 5), (14, 5), (15, 4), (15, 6)], (15, 6): [(16, 6), (14, 6), (15, 5), (15, 7)], (15, 7): [(16, 7), (14, 7), (15, 6), (15, 8)], (15, 8): [(16, 8), (14, 8), (15, 7), (15, 9)], (15, 9): [(16, 9), (14, 9), (15, 8), (15, 10)], (15, 10): [(16, 10), (14, 10), (15, 9), (15, 11)], (15, 11): [(16, 11), (14, 11), (15, 10), (15, 12)], (15, 12): [(16, 12), (14, 12), (15, 11), (15, 13)], (15, 13): [(16, 13), (14, 13), (15, 12), (15, 14)], (15, 14): [(16, 14), (14, 14), (15, 13), (15, 15)], (15, 15): [(16, 15), (14, 15), (15, 14), (15, 16)], (15, 16): [(16, 16), (14, 16), (15, 15), (15, 17)], (15, 17): [(16, 17), (14, 17), (15, 16), (15, 18)], (15, 18): [(16, 18), (14, 18), (15, 17), (15, 19)], (15, 19): [(16, 19), (14, 19), (15, 18), (15, 20)], (16, 0): [(17, 0), (15, 0), (16, -1), (16, 1)], (16, 1): [(17, 1), (15, 1), (16, 0), (16, 2)], (16, 2): [(17, 2), (15, 2), (16, 1), (16, 3)], (16, 3): [(17, 3), (15, 3), (16, 2), (16, 4)], (16, 4): [(17, 4), (15, 4), (16, 3), (16, 5)], (16, 5): [(17, 5), (15, 5), (16, 4), (16, 6)], (16, 6): [(17, 6), (15, 6), (16, 5), (16, 7)], (16, 7): [(17, 7), (15, 7), (16, 6), (16, 8)], (16, 8): [(17, 8), (15, 8), (16, 7), (16, 9)], (16, 9): [(17, 9), (15, 9), (16, 8), (16, 10)], (16, 10): [(17, 10), (15, 10), (16, 9), (16, 11)], (16, 11): [(17, 11), (15, 11), (16, 10), (16, 12)], (16, 12): [(17, 12), (15, 12), (16, 11), (16, 13)], (16, 13): [(17, 13), (15, 13), (16, 12), (16, 14)], (16, 14): [(17, 14), (15, 14), (16, 13), (16, 15)], (16, 15): [(17, 15), (15, 15), (16, 14), (16, 16)], (16, 16): [(17, 16), (15, 16), (16, 15), (16, 17)], (16, 17): [(17, 17), (15, 17), (16, 16), (16, 18)], (16, 18): [(17, 18), (15, 18), (16, 17), (16, 19)], (16, 19): [(17, 19), (15, 19), (16, 18), (16, 20)], (17, 0): [(18, 0), (16, 0), (17, -1), (17, 1)], (17, 1): [(18, 1), (16, 1), (17, 0), (17, 2)], (17, 2): [(18, 2), (16, 2), (17, 1), (17, 3)], (17, 3): [(18, 3), (16, 3), (17, 2), (17, 4)], (17, 4): [(18, 4), (16, 4), (17, 3), (17, 5)], (17, 5): [(18, 5), (16, 5), (17, 4), (17, 6)], (17, 6): [(18, 6), (16, 6), (17, 5), (17, 7)], (17, 7): [(18, 7), (16, 7), (17, 6), (17, 8)], (17, 8): [(18, 8), (16, 8), (17, 7), (17, 9)], (17, 9): [(18, 9), (16, 9), (17, 8), (17, 10)], (17, 10): [(18, 10), (16, 10), (17, 9), (17, 11)], (17, 11): [(18, 11), (16, 11), (17, 10), (17, 12)], (17, 12): [(18, 12), (16, 12), (17, 11), (17, 13)], (17, 13): [(18, 13), (16, 13), (17, 12), (17, 14)], (17, 14): [(18, 14), (16, 14), (17, 13), (17, 15)], (17, 15): [(18, 15), (16, 15), (17, 14), (17, 16)], (17, 16): [(18, 16), (16, 16), (17, 15), (17, 17)], (17, 17): [(18, 17), (16, 17), (17, 16), (17, 18)], (17, 18): [(18, 18), (16, 18), (17, 17), (17, 19)], (17, 19): [(18, 19), (16, 19), (17, 18), (17, 20)], (18, 0): [(19, 0), (17, 0), (18, -1), (18, 1)], (18, 1): [(19, 1), (17, 1), (18, 0), (18, 2)], (18, 2): [(19, 2), (17, 2), (18, 1), (18, 3)], (18, 3): [(19, 3), (17, 3), (18, 2), (18, 4)], (18, 4): [(19, 4), (17, 4), (18, 3), (18, 5)], (18, 5): [(19, 5), (17, 5), (18, 4), (18, 6)], (18, 6): [(19, 6), (17, 6), (18, 5), (18, 7)], (18, 7): [(19, 7), (17, 7), (18, 6), (18, 8)], (18, 8): [(19, 8), (17, 8), (18, 7), (18, 9)], (18, 9): [(19, 9), (17, 9), (18, 8), (18, 10)], (18, 10): [(19, 10), (17, 10), (18, 9), (18, 11)], (18, 11): [(19, 11), (17, 11), (18, 10), (18, 12)], (18, 12): [(19, 12), (17, 12), (18, 11), (18, 13)], (18, 13): [(19, 13), (17, 13), (18, 12), (18, 14)], (18, 14): [(19, 14), (17, 14), (18, 13), (18, 15)], (18, 15): [(19, 15), (17, 15), (18, 14), (18, 16)], (18, 16): [(19, 16), (17, 16), (18, 15), (18, 17)], (18, 17): [(19, 17), (17, 17), (18, 16), (18, 18)], (18, 18): [(19, 18), (17, 18), (18, 17), (18, 19)], (18, 19): [(19, 19), (17, 19), (18, 18), (18, 20)], (19, 0): [(20, 0), (18, 0), (19, -1), (19, 1)], (19, 1): [(20, 1), (18, 1), (19, 0), (19, 2)], (19, 2): [(20, 2), (18, 2), (19, 1), (19, 3)], (19, 3): [(20, 3), (18, 3), (19, 2), (19, 4)], (19, 4): [(20, 4), (18, 4), (19, 3), (19, 5)], (19, 5): [(20, 5), (18, 5), (19, 4), (19, 6)], (19, 6): [(20, 6), (18, 6), (19, 5), (19, 7)], (19, 7): [(20, 7), (18, 7), (19, 6), (19, 8)], (19, 8): [(20, 8), (18, 8), (19, 7), (19, 9)], (19, 9): [(20, 9), (18, 9), (19, 8), (19, 10)], (19, 10): [(20, 10), (18, 10), (19, 9), (19, 11)], (19, 11): [(20, 11), (18, 11), (19, 10), (19, 12)], (19, 12): [(20, 12), (18, 12), (19, 11), (19, 13)], (19, 13): [(20, 13), (18, 13), (19, 12), (19, 14)], (19, 14): [(20, 14), (18, 14), (19, 13), (19, 15)], (19, 15): [(20, 15), (18, 15), (19, 14), (19, 16)], (19, 16): [(20, 16), (18, 16), (19, 15), (19, 17)], (19, 17): [(20, 17), (18, 17), (19, 16), (19, 18)], (19, 18): [(20, 18), (18, 18), (19, 17), (19, 19)], (19, 19): [(20, 19), (18, 19), (19, 18), (19, 20)]}

for key in d:
    lst = []
    for (a, b) in d[key]:
        if 0 <= a <= 20 and 0 <= b <= 20:
            lst.append((a, b))
    d[key] = lst

print(d)
```

You could do it in fewer lines with [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) but I think this may be a bit clearer.